# MEAN Angular up-voting function throwing forbidden message

Tags: angularjs, meanjs

What im trying to do is create an app where users can post items and others can vote on the items similar to Reddit etc.

Problem i have is that when one user votes on an item posted by another user they get a forbidden message.

How i do i make it so that one user can modify the votes count of another users item.

This is the model for the Item

```
    var ItemSchema = new Schema({
    title: {
        type: String,
        default: 'NA',
        required: 'Please fill Item title',
        trim: true
    },
    link: {
        type: String,
        required: 'Please fill Item URL',
        trim: true
    },
    details: {
        type: String,
        default: 'NA',
        required: 'Please fill Item Details',
        trim: true
    },
    votes: {
        type: Number,
        default: '0'
    },
    voters: [{
        type: Schema.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User'
    }],
    created: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    },
    user: {
        type: Schema.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User'
    }

});
```

So one user should be able to increment the upvotes for another users Item.

Routes

```
      // Items collection routes
  app.route('/items').all(itemsPolicy.isAllowed)
      .get(items.list)
      .post(items.create);

  app.route('/items/itemCount').all()
      .get(items.countitems);

  app.route('/items/itemCountToday').all()
      .get(items.countitemsToday);


  // Single item routes
  app.route('/items/:itemId').all(itemsPolicy.isAllowed)
      .get(items.read)
      .put(items.update)
      .delete(items.delete);
```

Upvote function

```
$scope.upVoteHome = function(item) {
        item.votes++;
        item.$update(function() {
            //$location.path('items/' + item._id);
        }, function(errorResponse) {
            // rollback votes on fail also
            $scope.error = errorResponse.data.message;
        });
    };
```

Button

```
<button ng-show="authentication.user" ng-click="upVoteHome(item)" type="button"
 class="btn btn-danger vote-up-button"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-up"></i> Hot</button>
```

Comment: We need the rest of your code to try and understand the error your getting. Based just on your schema and from a data storage standpoint this should be possible with what you have. Each Item has a votes count, and a voters array to keep track of all the user ID that have voted on the Item.

Comment: Thanks. I assume its some kind of route issue. Ill post the routes and Controller method.

Comment: Based on your code looks like $scope.upVoteHome is going to make an HTTP PUT to /items/:itemId. My guess is your issue has to do with the routing middleware itemsPolicy.isAllowed. Can you paste the code for itemsPolicy.isAllowed?

Comment: And are you using https://github.com/meanjs/mean? I found something similar to .isAllowed() in their repo

Comment: I think ive cracked it. Ill post an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add a 'put' permission in the routing policy

```
  {
    roles: ['user'],
    allows: [{
      resources: '/deals',
      permissions: ['get', 'post', 'put']
    }, {
      resources: '/deals/:dealId',
      permissions: ['get', 'put']
    }]
  }
```